# ImageView image not showing

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I have FXML form with the following structure. I tried loading the image into image view in different ways. However, it is not working.

```xml
<GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="header" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="228.0" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="50"  />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="261.0" minWidth="10.0" fillWidth="true" percentWidth="50"  />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <ImageView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
            fx:id="ImgViewBanner"
            pickOnBounds="true"  preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="file:src/images/banner.png" backgroundLoading="true" />
            </image>                        
        </ImageView>
        <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            <Label text="English - English">
                <font>
                    <Font size="48" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Advanced Learners' Dictionary" >
                <font>
                    <Font size="24" />
                </font>
            </Label>
        </VBox>                          
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

I have put my image under these directories.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is placed in the same directory as the fxml file, you should be able to use `@` to specify a resource location relative to the fxml file:

```xml
<Image url="@banner.PNG" backgroundLoading="true" />
```

See [*Introduction to FXML: Local Resource Resolution*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution)

Comment: How do you load the fxml?

Comment: Found the answer, it's with the grid pane column size. Since both column 1 and 3 are sized to 50 percent of the windows width, the image is displayed outside of the form. Guess I have to study more about layout and sizing.